# Exchanging TWD to USD in Taiwan

Tags: money, exchange, taiwan

Where can I exchange TWD to USD before leaving Taiwan? Is doing this at TPE airport a good option (I've heard the exhchange rates there are good, unlike other airports), or is it better to go to a bank in Taipei? In the latter case, does any bank exchange money? I haven't seen any currency exchange points (in contrast to Hong Kong where they are plentiful).

Comment: Bank of Taiwan (at least at the airport) charges 100 NTD for exchanges of NTD to foreign currency. Not sure about Mega Bank (which is also present at the airport).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**At a bank**. There are at least two in the airport. Bank of Taiwan is government owned and gives a fair exchange rate, so if you are going to the airport, no need to stop by a bank elsewhere on the way.

Comment: It looks like Bank of Taiwan at TPE opens at 9:00 AM, but my flight is at 9:50 AM, so I should probably go through security before 9 AM. Does any bank in the city offer currency exchange? Can I see the rates online?

Comment: Many big banks in Taiwan offer exchange. I used HSBC and another one which I don't recall the name last year.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong: according to the airport website, there are several branches of Bank of Taiwan at the airport, and at least one of them is open 24 hours.